# When are substitution questions too broad?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

[This](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/41247/vegetarian-or-vegan-alternative-to-oyster) question about vegan substitutions for oysters was closed, and after editing, a user pointed out that it is still very broad. There are, however, [many](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/3120/buttermilk-substitute) [broad](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/11543/substitute-for-marjoram) [substitution](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/368/mayonnaise-substitutes) [questions](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/4192/with-what-can-i-replace-eggs). Are there standards for how broad is too broad?